# What is exactly a 'bakery fee'?

Tags: bakery, tezos-reward-distributor

I need to configure my TRD. I got to enter my 'bakery fee' field. Is it a fee that baker pays for the staked amount to delegator? Say, my bakery was delegated with 100 tz, and I got 9% bakery fee, so my final reward is 9%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about the `service_fee`, that's how much the baker charges for the service from the share of the delegator. Read more about TRD configuration: https://tezos-reward-distributor-organization.github.io/tezos-reward-distributor/configuration.html

Comment: To elaborate, the 'bakery fee' also known as 'service_fee' is how much the baker keeps from each delegators rewards. So if Bob delegates 1000 tez to you, and his reward for the cycle is 5 tez, with a service_fee of 10%, you keep 0.5 tez and Bob receives 4.5 tez. There are examples on TRD documentation.